# On Windows, when will a 'socket()' call return WSAEINVALIDPROCTABLE?

Tags: sockets, winapi, winsock2

Suppose our client application does as below:

```
WSADATA wsa_data;
int     ret;
SOCKET  sock;
ret = WSAStartup (MAKEWORD (2, 2), &wsa_data);
if (ret ==0) {
  sock = socket (AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPROTO_UDP);
}
```

When will it happen that `sock == INVALID_SOCKET` and `WSAGetLastError()` would return `WSAEINVALIDPROCTABLE`?

Microsoft's documentation for the [`socket()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket) function says it can return `WSAEINVALIDPROCTABLE` when:

> The service provider returned an invalid or incomplete procedure table to the WSPStartup.

Can a TCP/IP transport service provider, that is not a custom service provider, return an invalid or incomplete procedure table to the `WSPStartup()` during a `socket()` call? If yes, why? Under what circumstances? And how can it be remedied?

Comment: That goes back to the days that winsock was not owned by Microsoft but an effort from the many network vendors to create a common api.  They could supply a provider to get the product supported on Windows.  They are all out of business so this error never occurs anymore.

Comment: You can terminate the process when raising the errors with this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket#example-code).