# On Windows, when will a 'socket()' call return WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT?

Tags: sockets, winapi, winsock2

Suppose our client application does as below:

```
WSADATA wsa_data;
int     ret;
SOCKET  sock;
ret = WSAStartup (MAKEWORD (2, 2), &wsa_data);
if (ret ==0) {
  sock = socket (AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPROTO_UDP);
}
```

When will it happen that `sock == INVALID_SOCKET` and `WSAGetLastError()` would return `WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT`?

Microsoft's documentation for the [`socket()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket) function says it can return `WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT` when:

> The service provider failed to initialize. This error is returned if a layered service provider (LSP) or namespace provider was improperly installed or the provider fails to operate correctly.

Can a TCP/IP transport service provider, that is not a custom service provider, fail to initialize during a `socket()` call? If yes, why? Under what circumstances? And how can it be remedied?

Comment: [terminate the process when raising these errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket#example-code).

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73697326/on-windows-when-will-socket-call-return-wsaeinvalidproctable that you asked at the same time.

Comment: @Anders that other question is not really a duplicate, though. Yes, the wording is similar, but it is asking about a completely different error code. Rather than asking a single question about all of the possible errors that `socket()` can fail with, and risk having it be closed as too broad, it makes sense to ask a separate question about each error code individually (within reason, as there are 13 documented errors that `socket()` can report on failure).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes but 1) You cannot trust MSDN to list all possible codes and 2) Both of them are LSP related and since they can be written by anyone there is no way to know which error they return and when/why...

Answer (score 1):

It will probably never happen with the default provider and unlikely with a 3rd-party provider.

`WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT` can be returned by Windows itself if it cannot load the provider or if it can't find the `WSPStartup` or more likely `NSPStartup` exported function. I'm not sure if this can only happen during `WSAStartup` or if Windows is allowed to delay this call until the provider is needed.

A provider itself can presumably fail with `WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT` at any time. Imagine a LSP that logs every connection but for whatever reason there is a problem with the database it is using and it might choose to fail the socket with this error.

(All of this is speculation and you should not handle each possible error in a specific way unless you have a reason to.)

Comment: provider loaded during first call to `WSASocketW` which reference it. in clear windows, this is *mswsock.dll* for tcp/udp

Answer (score 1):

It can happen when trying to load a 3rd party provider into a Windows Protected process, for example. Microsoft allows only loading DLLs that are either signed by Microsoft or signed with a special certificate. This is not always the case.